# Run Perl in Browser with PerlTray

Tags: html, perl

I am using perl tray from activestate and have a question. I am wanting to make some type of ui or way for a user to set "Settings" on my application. These settings can just be written / read from a text file that is stored on the users computer.

The part I am not understanding though is how to go about making a ui. The only thing i can think of is showing a local perl page that runs on their computer to write to the file. However, I'm not sure how i could get perl to run in the browser when only using perltray.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

PerlTray is an odd duck.  It has an implicit event loop that kicks in after you either fall off the end of your program or after your 1st call to `exit()`.  This makes it incompatible with most other common GUI event loops or most mini-server techniques that operate in the same process & thread.

2 possibilities come to mind:

- Most Likely you'll have success spawning a thread or process that creates a traditional perl GUI or a mini-server hosting your configuration web-app.  I'd probably pick Tkx, but that's just my preference.
- I have a suspicion that the Event Loop used by Win32::GUI may actually be compatible with the event loop in PerlTray, but some experimentation would be required to verify that.  I generally avoid Win32::GUI because it's not platform independent, but if you're using PerlTray, you're tied to Windows anyway...